# Windows phone emulator to access localhost web service

Tags: xamarin, uwp, localhost, emulation, windows-10-mobile

I have a webservice that I am running on a localhost (seperate project with .asmx file), and then I have a Xamarin UWP phone app that takes an input of a product code and returns certain information about it from the web service.

When I run the app in simulator mode it can connect to the local host however when I run it on a windows 10 phone emulator through visual studio it cannot connect to local host. This is a problem as I need to take screenshots of the app working in the Phone emulator.

Can anyone off suggestions to solve this please.

Comment: when you run it on the emulator, "localhost" is the address of the emulator, not the server.  You need to use the IP or FQDN of the server.

Comment: You can find your network in emulator and then call the server's ip.

Comment: I also need help with this issue.